# HTML5 Canvas Collision Detection

Tags: html, canvas, collision, detection

So I have been looking around and trying tutorials but I can't seem to get any collision detection systems to work. If someone would be able to explain what I am doing wrong or any syntax errors that would be great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bouncing Ball</title>
<style>
    #mycanvas {
        outline: 1px solid #000;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="1280" height="750"></canvas>

    <script>

        var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var xx = 50;
        var yy = 100;

        var velY = 0;
        var velX = 0;
        var speed = 6;
        var friction = 0.7;
        var keys = [];

        var velocity = 0;
        var acceleration = 1;




        function physics() {
            velocity+=acceleration;
            yy += velocity;

            if(yy   >   597) {
                var temp =0;
                temp =velocity/4;
                velocity=-temp;
                yy =    597;
            }
        }


        function collision(first, second){
            return !(first.x > second.x + second.width || first.x + first.width < second.x || first.y > second.y + second.height || first.y + first.height < second.y);
        }


        var player = {
            color: "#2B2117",
            x: xx,
            y: yy,
            width: 75,
            height: 75,
            draw: function() {
                ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
                ctx.fillRect(xx, yy, this.width, this.height);
            }
        }

        var floor = {
            color: "#A67437",
            x: 0,
            y: 670,
            width: 1280,
            height: 80,
            draw: function() {
                ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }
        }


        var bucket = {
            color: "#B25E08",
            x: 300,
            y: 600,
            width: 50,
            height: 100,
            draw: function() {
                ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }
        }


        function update() {
            if (keys[39]) {
                if (velX < speed) {
                velX+=3;
                }
            }
            if (keys[37]) {
                if (velX > -speed) {
                    velX--;
                }
            }
            if (keys[32]) {
                velY -= 1.5;
                velY += 1;
            }
            velX *= friction;
            xx += velX;
            yy += velY;


            physics();
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.rect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#EEE3B9";
            ctx.fill();
            floor.draw();
            bucket.draw();
            player.draw();

            if  (collision(player, bucket)) {
                console.log('collision');
            }


            setTimeout(update, 10);
        }

        update();
        document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
                keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        });
        document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
                keys[e.keyCode] = false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only append to what markE already says in his answer (we seem to be working on this simultaneously :) ).

I will first point out a more serious bug in the code:

You are using `fill()` without a `beginPath()` first. This will slow down the code loop rapidly. Replace `fill()` with a `fillRect()` instead.

Also, there is no need to use `clearRect()` when the next draw operation fills the entire canvas:

```
//ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle = "#EEE3B9";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

You're using global vars `xx`/`yy`. One main point of using objects is to avoid global vars. The render method uses the same so it appears to work, but the player's local properties are never updated. Remove global vars and only work with the object's `x` and `y` (I would recommend some refactoring so you can pass in the object to the `physics()` etc. instead of doing global referencing).

<del>`var xx = 50;
var yy = 100;`</del>

To:

```
var player = {
  x: 50,    // numbers cannot be referenced, their value
  y: 100,   // is copied. Use these properties directly instead..
  // ...
  draw: function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);  // and here..
  }
}
```

and

```
function physics() {
  //...
  player.y += velocity;

  if (player.y > 597) {
    //...
    player.y = 597;
  }
}
```

and in the loop:

```
player.x += velX;
player.y += velY;
```

Add `preventDefault()` in you key handlers to prevent the key moves to affect the brower's window scroll (not all users have a large screen so the left/right key will also affect the scrolling).

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
```

And of course, use `requestAnimationFrame` to loop the animation.

I would also recommend using a function object that can be instantiated as you have methods in all of them. With a function object you can prototype the `draw()` method and share it across all the instances without the need of extra memory (and it's good for the internal optimizer as well). This if you plan to draw more than those three objects.

**Updated code**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var velY = 0;
var velX = 0;
var speed = 6;
var friction = 0.7;
var keys = [];

var velocity = 0;
var acceleration = 1;

function physics() {
  velocity += acceleration;
  player.y += velocity;

  if (player.y > 597) {
    var temp = 0;
    temp = velocity / 4;
    velocity = -temp;
    player.y = 597;
  }
}

function collision(first, second) {
  return !(first.x > second.x + second.width || first.x + first.width < second.x || first.y > second.y + second.height || first.y + first.height < second.y);
}

var player = {
  color: "#2B2117",
  x: 50,
  y: 100,
  width: 75,
  height: 75,
  draw: function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
}

var floor = {
  color: "#A67437",
  x: 0,
  y: 670,
  width: 1280,
  height: 80,
  draw: function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
}

var bucket = {
  color: "#B25E08",
  x: 300,
  y: 600,
  width: 50,
  height: 100,
  draw: function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
}

function update() {
  if (keys[39]) {
    if (velX < speed) {
      velX += 3;
    }
  }
  else if (keys[37]) {
    if (velX > -speed) {
      velX -= 3;
    }
  }
  else if (keys[32]) {
    velY -= 1.5;
    velY += 1;
  }
  velX *= friction;

  player.x += velX;
  player.y += velY;
  physics();

  //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // not really needed
  ctx.fillStyle = "#EEE3B9";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);    // as this clears too...
  floor.draw();
  bucket.draw();
  player.draw();

  if (collision(player, bucket)) {
    console.log('collision');
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
update();

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

```css
#mycanvas {outline: 1px solid #000;}
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="1280" height="750"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

**There's no problem with your collision function--it will correctly recognize the collision between any 2 un-rotated rectangles.**

Visually, your black rect drops to the floor, bounces once or twice and then settles on the floor.

**3 issues though...**

1. I do see that your `setTimeout` is set to trigger every 10ms. That's a bit fast since the display will only refresh about every 1000/60=16.67ms--so your setTimeout should be at least 16.67. Also, You might consider using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of setTimeout because rAF synchronizes itself with the display and gives better performance.
2. One design glitch, even if the user constantly holds down the right-key to move the rect towards the bucket as fast as possible, the rect is never given enough "delta X" to hit the bucket.
3. You are testing collisions with `player` and `bucket` but you are not updating the player.x & player.y. Therefore your collision() is only testing the initial player position and not its current position.

   ```
   // in update()
   ...
   player.x=xx;
   player.y=yy;
   ```

Demo of refactored code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var xx = 50;
var yy = 100;

var velY = 0;
var velX = 0;
var speed = 6;
var friction = 0.7;
var keys = [];

var velocity = 0;
var acceleration = 1;




function physics() {
  velocity+=acceleration;
  yy += velocity;

  if(yy   >   597) {
    var temp =0;
    temp =velocity/4;
    velocity=-temp;
    yy =    597;
  }
}


function collision(first, second){
  return !(first.x > second.x + second.width || first.x + first.width < second.x || first.y > second.y + second.height || first.y + first.height < second.y);
}


var player = {
  color: "#2B2117",
  x: xx,
  y: yy,
  width: 75,
  height: 75,
  draw: function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(xx, yy, this.width, this.height);
  }
}

var floor = {
  color: "#A67437",
  x: 0,
  y: 670,
  width: 1280,
  height: 80,
  draw: function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
}


var bucket = {
  color: "#B25E08",
  x: 50,
  y: 600,
  width: 50,
  height: 100,
  draw: function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
}


function update() {
  if (keys[39]) {
    if (velX < speed) {
      velX+=3;
    }
  }
  if (keys[37]) {
    if (velX > -speed) {
      velX--;
    }
  }
  if (keys[32]) {
    velY -= 1.5;
    velY += 1;
  }
  velX *= friction;
  xx += velX;
  yy += velY;

  //
  player.x=xx;
  player.y=yy;


  physics();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.rect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#EEE3B9";
  ctx.fill();
  floor.draw();
  bucket.draw();
  player.draw();

  if  (collision(player, bucket)) {
    alert('collision when player at:'+player.x+"/"+player.y);
  }else{
    setTimeout(update, 1000/60*3);
  }


}

update();
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="1280" height="750"></canvas>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not enough delta X? Sorry I am very new to Javascript and pretty much programming in general

Comment: Delta-X is the change in X coordinates the player can be moved before the player hits the ground. In your case, the user can move the player rightward holding down the right-arrow-key, but the player will hit the ground before the player can be moved over the bucket.

Comment: okay, I moved the bucket directly underneath but still nothing happens. I just am looking to try and get some reaction from a collision detection.

Comment: Ok, I took another look at your code and discovered you're not changing `player.x` & `player.y` as `xx` and `yy` change. You must do this otherwise your `collision()` is only testing the initial position of the player. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste

```
<html>
<head>
<title> new </title>
<script>
var ctx1;
var ctx;

var balls = [
{x:50, y:50, r:20, m:1, vx:1, vy:1.5},
{x:200, y:80, r:30, m:1, vx:-1, vy:0.3},
];

function start() 
{
    ctx1 = document.getElementById("ctx");
    ctx = ctx1.getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    setInterval(draw, 10); 
}

function draw()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx1.width, ctx1.height);
    for (var a = 0; a < balls.length; a ++) 
{
    for (var b = 0; b < balls.length; b ++)
{
    if (a != b) 
{
    var distToBalls = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(balls[a].x - balls[b].x, 2) + Math.pow(balls[a].y - balls[b].y, 2));
    if (distToBalls <= balls[a].r + balls[b].r) 
{
    var newVel = getBallCollision(balls[a], balls[b]); 
    balls[a].vx = newVel.ball1.vx;
    balls[a].vy = newVel.ball1.vy;
    balls[b].vx = newVel.ball2.vx;
    balls[b].vy = newVel.ball2.vy;
    balls[a].x += balls[a].vx;
    balls[a].y += balls[a].vy;
    balls[b].x += balls[b].vx;
    balls[b].y += balls[b].vy;
}
}
}
}

for (var a = 0; a < balls.length; a ++) 
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(balls[a].x, balls[a].y, balls[a].r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    if (balls[a].x <= balls[a].r) balls[a].vx *= -1;
    if (balls[a].y <= balls[a].r) balls[a].vy *= -1;
    if (balls[a].x >= ctx1.width - balls[a].r) balls[a].vx *= -1;
    if (balls[a].y >= ctx1.height - balls[a].r) balls[a].vy *= -1;
    balls[a].x += balls[a].vx;
    balls[a].y += balls[a].vy;
}
}
function getBallCollision(b1, b2) 
{
var dx = b1.x - b2.x;
var dy = b1.y - b2.y;
var dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
if (Math.abs(dy) + Math.abs(dx) != 0 && dist <= b1.r + b2.r) 
    {
    var colAng = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    var sp1 = Math.sqrt(b1.vx*b1.vx + b1.vy*b1.vy);
    var sp2 = Math.sqrt(b2.vx*b2.vx + b2.vy*b2.vy);
    var dir1 = Math.atan2(b1.vy, b1.vx);
    var dir2 = Math.atan2(b2.vy, b2.vx);
    var vx1 = sp1 * Math.cos(dir1 - colAng);
    var vy1 = sp1 * Math.sin(dir1 - colAng);
    var vx2 = sp2 * Math.cos(dir2 - colAng);
    var vy2 = sp2 * Math.sin(dir2 - colAng);
    var fvx1 = ((b1.m - b2.m) * vx1 + (2 * b2.m) * vx2) / (b1.m + b2.m);
    var fvx2 = ((2 * b1.m) * vx1 + (b2.m - b1.m) * vx2) / (b1.m + b2.m);
    var fvy1 = vy1;
    var fvy2 = vy2;
    b1.vx = Math.cos(colAng) * fvx1 + Math.cos(colAng + Math.PI/2) * fvy1;
    b1.vy = Math.sin(colAng) * fvx1 + Math.sin(colAng + Math.PI/2) * fvy1;
    b2.vx = Math.cos(colAng) * fvx2 + Math.cos(colAng + Math.PI/2) * fvy2;
    b2.vy = Math.sin(colAng) * fvx2 + Math.sin(colAng + Math.PI/2) * fvy2;
    return { ball1:b1, ball2:b2 }; 
    }
else return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="start();">
<canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="300" style = "border : 2px solid #854125 ;"> </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some explanation about what OPs problem is and how this helps would be good.